# Subversion with Continuous Integration

Tags: svn, continuous-integration

Sorry if answers to this question already exist, I did not find them yet.

I'm member of a web development team, we maintain a web portal. Release Management works with Subversion. This is how I work when adding new features to the portal:

- Create a new Branch by copying the Trunk
- Develop in that Branch
- Periodically merge updates from the Trunk into that Branch (I want to know if Framework-Changes break my code, before it goes to UAT / Integration, e.g.)
- Re-Integrate the Branch into the Trunk in order to let it go live

Now we have a problem with Continuous Integration:

- Periodical Go-Live every X weeks
- Several Branches exist which are planned to go-live on different dates
- Every X hours a day, Integration Server does a Trunk checkout and merges all Branches (which should explicitly go to Integration System) into it
- The Trunk updates which have been merged into each Branch (see above) now generate Tree Conflicts

What is the Best Practice for that? Re-Integrating doesn't work for merging multiple Branches, because as soon as one Branch is integrates, the working copy isn't clean anymore. However, Continuous Integration must be possible somehow...

If Trank changes are merged into each Branch, different revisions are created. But the files should have the same content and be equal. Isn't there a merge-option saying "ignore a conflict if the two new/changed files are identical"?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you described is **not continuous integration** because of the following requirement:

> Every X hours a day, Integration Server does a Trunk checkout and
>   merges all Branches (which should explicitly go to Integration System)
>   into it

Real `Continuous integration` includes following steps:

- Updating source code from *one specific* branch (`trunk`, for example).
- Building source code producing build artifact which could be either executed or deployed. Sometimes this phase includes also running unit-tests and inspections.
- Shows build status, whether it was successful or not: green or red.

If you have several branches, it means that you need to configure several build plans for several branches in order to perform continuous integration for each branch separately.

Therefore, there could be no best practice for what you described because merges should always be performed manually. This is due to the merging conflicts. They happen quite often and can be resolved only manually. Continuous integration won't help.

If you just confused with terms and want to perform what you described anyway, I would say that your development process is little bit flawed. Probably, you do not need to perform merging from several branches simultaneously. All development you deliver most often should be concentrated in one branch. Most often such 'one' branch would be trunk.

In your case it seems that valuable development is dispersed between several branches. That's not right. Once you decide that some functionality should be included into upcoming release, it should be integrated into one (probably parent) branch and stay there as a part of the codebase. Try to reduce number of branches you have.

To sum up,

1. Exclude `merge all branches` step from your process (this is not to be done automatically).
2. Do merging *manually* instead.
3. In case you sure you need to have branches all the time, configure continuous integration for such *each branch separately*.
4. Otherwise (you do not need to keep branches all the time, and they can be easily reintegrated into parent branch once the development is finished) *reduce number of branches to a minimum*.

Good luck!

Comment: I see your point. Merging manually works fine today if branches should go-live. Separate Integration Systems should also work fine, I agree. However, our customers currently have _one_ UAT System where they test and approve changes. It would be hard to explain why they now should test each feature in separate systems... Or do I still miss something?

Comment: You do not need to explain anything. Just merge changes from other branches manually into mainline branch (trunk). Mainline will have all changes/functionality you need because you've merged them explicitly. Therefore, you would be able to build and deploy content of mainline straight onto UAT without being afraid there's something missing.

Comment: No, sorry, that's not possible. In our environment, merging changes into the trunk just means they will go-live with the next deployment. This is why we don't have problems with go-live, but with UAT. In addition: It does not mean that a branch is planned to go-live with the next deployment, just because it's available on the UAT system - it can remain there for a long time (which may just be caused by customers who just don't have time for testing). Trunk should only reflect live ressources.

Comment: Processes are seriously flawed if application can go live (production) before UAT. Or you mean something else saying 'go-live'?

Comment: Technically, they _can_. For sure, they _shouldn't_. A change planned go to prod must be re-integrated from a branch into a trunk. So your proposal of manually merging all branches into the trunk would help to avoid conflicts on the comprehencive UAT system - but would also mean that all branches go to prod with the next planned deployment. In other words: With our concept, the trunk has to be avoided if a branch should not go live. The problem to have one comprehencive UAT system which shows all changes of all branches to enable a "big approval" remains... BTW: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MichaelDrewek: You can accept the answer if you think it addresses your question and you can assume it describes an acceptable solution for your case.

Comment: It indeed describes an acceptable solution, and thanks for the hint. However, I'm looking for a Best Practice and hope for some more answers with different approaches. Finally, I will surely accept one of them :-)

Comment: I get exactly what you were saying here Michael. This is the corporate environment I had recently and am still confused about CI. We had QA and UAT for a particular branch. Sometimes a branch would get merged together and go for further testing. When we were scheduled for Beta, we could move the QA/UAT passed branch to root and begin Beta test, basically owning the root until our branch's code was in the next deployment. Some maintenance fixes might be merged up as well.