# Subversion, Continuous Integration, and Scrum

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, agile, scrum

How do we set up a Subversion policy so that we can easily "back out" a whole story worth of changes, while maintaining continuous integration?

---

In my place of business, we're getting Scrum going where we had no process/"cowboy coding" before. That's a lot of fun (Dwarf Fortress definition), but not the focus of this question.

In Scrum, we have the possibility of the product owner having the authority to say "no" to a story completion, or perhaps work not being "done" on a story during a sprint. The idea is that if something isn't "done", it doesn't get deployed. There's disagreement internally - some folks say that we should deploy the half done stuff "tied off" so it can't be used, but I strongly disagree (that's another topic entirely).

With continuous integration, developers are encouraged to commit often to identify integration/regression issues early. For us, that means subversion commits, largely with the release branching pattern, though that is flexible.

If we're continuously committing to whatever branch, call it the sprint branch, what happens when we (rarely!) get to the end of a sprint and have a story that can't deploy? I'd need to "unmerge" any changes that supported that story from the deploying branch. Is there a branching policy/commit strategy that makes this relatively doable, without large-scale manual interaction? Should I even worry about it?

Related: [Subversion with Continuous Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176551/subversion-with-continuous-integration?rq=1)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (Unfortunately, this question is too old to be  migrated.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any easy solution.  Once you "unmerge/undo" your changes, which could be difficult, you'd have to re-test everything.  A better strategy if you end up in the case where you have a branch that cannot go to production would be to deploy an older build which is ready.  Then the new branch can be deployed once it is ready.

Comment: This would be pre-QA with CI, so the testing would be re-run largely automatically. Also, why would I want to delay an entire sprint's worth of "done" work for one broken story?

Comment: If it is pre-QA then I think you want a branch per story.  Once the story passes CI you merge it into the master branch.  If you then run into a case where QA finds an issue just before the release you either have to pull the story out and re-test or just hold off on releasing until you get it fixed.

Comment: @Dave I was thinking on similar lines, but one branch per story seems like it could lead to merge/integration hell, defeating the purpose of CI.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, I agree it could lead to a lot of merging if your stories are very small.  We do this frequently though and it is fine unless you have several people working on the same area of code especially if you use a good merge tool. The other advantage of this is that all your commits are on the branch so it is easier to do code-reviews.